# Can PCA help me in determining effect of multiple variables on other variable?

Tags: r, pca

I have a dataset containing 2000 soil property measured values and other attributes like slope, TWI, aspect, rainfall etc for the same. I want to see how my soil property changes with the change in slope, TWI, aspect etc. and which parameter affects the most(soil property). Is PCA a useful technique for this, or shall I go for some other statistical method?

Comment: Just for clarification: is "soil property" one variable? Or is it a set of variables? If it's just one variable, then regression might fit better your goal, as AWashburn answer says (and as others said in another question of yours), but if "soil property" is composed by a handful of variables, PCA might be useful.

Comment: -1 because this is an EXACT duplicate of another question that you posted under different account with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

PCA is considered a non-supervised method (you don't train with a dependent variable) and extracts useful "meta-information".  In short it is generally hard to find the kind of interpretation you want from PCA

A multiple regression (lm function in R) would allow you to see if and how much the soil property is affected by other effects in the model.  It would also be okay at prediction but there are other methods that might be better at prediction like LDA or K nearest neighbors (only if you have much more data than features).

Comment: One addition, if you use linear regression make sure you check for diagnostics before making any inferences. PCA is more of a feature selection method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to squeeze some interpretation out of PCA from the principal components.

Taking the principal components and the original variable values, you can determine how much they vary.

[image]

You can see from the above example that principal_component_1 is strongly correlated with housing, health, transportation, arts and education.